# Problema al leer los datos de una colección en firebasestore desde flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firestore

```dart
validarDatos() async{
    try{
        FirebaseFirestore ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
        CollectionReference collectionReferenceusuarios = ref.collection('Usuarios');
        QuerySnapshot usuarios = await collectionReferenceusuarios.get();

        usuarios.docs.forEach((documento) {
            logger.i(documento.data());
        });

    }catch(e){
        print('ERROR'+e.toString());
    }
}
```

En la función `validarDatos()` al llegar al `QuerySnapshot` esta no entra al `forEach` y salta el procesamiento de los datos encontrados en la colección

Comment: ¿Sabes si la variable docs contiene datos? Podrías hacer un print justo antes del forEach con el tamaño de la colección para ver si vienen datos o está vacío.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba algo similar, pero no logré saber por qué sucedia y reemplace el `forEach` por un `For-in`:

```
for(var doc in usuarios.docs){
     logger.i(doc.data());
}
```

haciendo ese cambio me funcionó a mi, no tengo claro si era algo respecto al `forEach`. Pero esa fue la solución que me sirvió, porque también se saltaba el bucle y nunca entraba.